# Pip exception error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to reinstall pip due to an error that happens when I try to install new libraries or even when I try to uninstall pip itself.
I reach that part where it asks for confirmation and then gives me the error.   The error it throws is the following (this one is the one it throws when doing "pip uninstall pip"):

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
  status =  self.run(options,args)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 76, in run

  requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 305, in uninstall
  req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
  paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

 File "usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
  renames(path, new_path)

 File "usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils.__init__.py", line 315, in renames
  shutil.move(old, new)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
  os.unlink(src)

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/pip'`
```

Comment: Did you try to run it as sudo?

Comment: No, thank you so much :D
It worked. Although, doesn't sudo force it? I read somewhere that pip shouldn't be run with sudo.

Comment: That depends on your system configuration and user permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to install some Python packages on a directory in which your user has no write privileges. You will have to do it with `sudo` first:

```
sudo pip install <package_name>
```

Or you could use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), and install packages without using sudo.

Answer (score 3):

It may be causing because you may not be running CMD as an administrator, run cmd as administrator.

Comment: Look at the paths in the stack trace. OP is not running Windows. I'm sure this answer is correct in general terms but the advice to "run `cmd` as an administrator" is way off beam.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the error message is saying that you don't have the administrative rights. 
You can open a new command prompt window directly to a folder location by right-clicking the folder in Windows while holding the Shift key and then selecting Open Command Window here. But this opens it to user-level privileges. However, you can add a shortcut to the right-click context menu that opens it with administrator privileges.

Open Notepad, insert the following text, and save as **AddToOpenAsAdmin.reg**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open Command Window Here as Administrator"
"Icon"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\imageres.dll,-78"
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

Then to apply, execute the **AddToOpenAsAdmin.reg**. Now you'll see an option when right-clicking a folder while holding down Shift key.

Hopefully now you won't get this error.

If you still get the fatal error with pip, you can type this code

```
python -m pip install libraryName
```

in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for my Mac:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is a permission error when trying to uninstall pip. This could be because the user running the command does not have the necessary permissions to uninstall pip from the system indicating:

- *User may be running CMD as **NON-administrator***
- *User's **DNS** may be causing this*

To fix this issue, you can **try running the command with sudo** privileges. For example:

`sudo pip uninstall pip`

or ***Run CMD as an Administrator*** in Windows

> This should prompt you for your password and then run the command with
> elevated privileges, allowing you to uninstall pip from the system.

Also, **try and change your DNS** to Google's DNS or any other

Alternatively, you could try using a virtual environment to install and manage your Python packages, rather than installing them system-wide. This can help avoid issues with permissions and package conflicts.